# The status of head in this linked list

Tags: c++

My mind is confused at the moment:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
}

void Print(Node *head) {

}
```

This is a code snippet from [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/). While this is easy, I just started wondering something: **If I modify the head in the Print function, does it modify the original head in the main as well, or is it just the local variable head that is modified?**

Comment: You can modify head but you can't modify the pointer passed in.

Answer (score 5):

You passed in a pointer by value, if you modify that pointer then it will not affect the original.

However if you modify what is pointed to by that pointer then it will affect the original.

For instance `head = nullptr;` would not, while `head->data = 1;` would.

Also note that any recursion you do will similarly change the original data, for instance an algorithm to add to the end of the list:

```
Node* previous = head
Node* current = head->next;
while (current != nullptr)
{
    previous = current;
    current = previous->next;
}
previous->next = new Node(); //However you create one.
```

Since it uses `head->next` and eventually modifies the result it will modify the original list.

Comment: I'd add that if the concern is whether you can use the `head` pointer passed to the function to traverse the list, then yes, you can.

Comment: So, if I modify what this pointer points to, the original pointer will still point to the old value, I guess. Nice. How do I pass a pointer by reference then?

Comment: @Southee: It depends on what you are passing into `Print`, if it is a raw value, you can use `Node &head`, if it is a pointer then `Node* &head`. The former will pas a `Node` by reference and the latter will pass a pointer to a `Node` by reference.